# devise gem and jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm using the devise gem (1.4.2) and rails (3.0.7). I've got a view with some check boxes and some jquery set up such that when I check a box it does a post which is handled by one of my controllers. Unfortunately, when I do this, it signs the current user out. Is there an easy way to avoid this? Thanks!

jquery code:

```
$(‘.do_some_action).live(‘change’, function(){
  $.post(‘/my_model/do_some_action’, {param1 : param1Value})
   return false
})
```

base controller:

```
class AuthorizedController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  check_authorization
  load_and_authorize_resource

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    redirect_to request.referer
  end
end
```

specific controller:

```
class MyModelsController < AuthorizedController
  ...
  def some_action
    ...
  end
end
```

-Jordan

Comment: We....need....codes... – user482594 3 mins ago

Comment: still not enough code :) this is to abstract to say anything concrete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you aren't passing the CSFR token in your AJAX requests.

Make sure the CSFR meta tag is being set by calling `csrf_meta_tag` in the HTML . Then you can use the below bit of JavaScript to ensure the CSFR tag is set on any AJAX requests.

```
$.ajaxSetup({beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")); }});
```

You can also disable the CSFR check for that action by adding the below in your controller, but the JavaScript alternative would be better.

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```